# Width of div regardless of screen size

Tags: html, css

On this new site i'm working on, the bar at bottom (part of the footer) should run from the bottom right of content all the way to the left hand side of your screen. For my screen size, I set it at a width of 1120px, but when viewed on a bigger screen it needs more width, therefore I need a suitable solution. Even just setting it as % i'm unsure if this is correct.

84% for my mac screen would be suitable. but again that's only to suit me and my screen here.
screenshot of the final outcome I need (for all screen sizes.) - http://cl.ly/TVp6

live url: http://bit.ly/1bijza0

**html**

```
<section id="footer"></section>
```

**css**

```
#footer { background-color: #242424; height: 40px; width: 1120px; border-bottom-right-radius: 20px; }
```

Comment: Remove the width. `display: block;` will extend an element to fill it's parent.

Comment: Without a width it stretches 100% of the screen. Needs to end at the bottom of the right of the main content/container.

Comment: You need some JavaScript to adjust the width, or you need a fixed margin on the left (rather than center your `#wrapper <div>`)

Comment: I suggest you use `display:block` to your `#footer` and put it inside a `<div>` and define a `padding` to the div and perhaps also define `width:100%` to the div

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make it display:block; and then set a left and right margin?